# Is it possible to make the edges of a curved mesh smooth while keeping it low poly?

Tags: modeling, topology, subdivision-surface

[image: The top is what it looks like in lower poly and the bottom is how I want the edge to look like]

I am building an aircraft that has wings curved from the top and side and since I pay close attention to detail, I want to make the edges as round as I can, but using 5 subdivisions bumps the vertice count to 3 million. I know that normals exist, but I'm not sure if they can do anything about this. The reason why I have to apply the modifier is because I will be texturing it in substance painter and will be applying decals in very precise locations of the model. Smooth shading works in the middle of the model, but the edges look very bad. Is there any way to make a low poly curve look smooth or do I have to deal with 3 million vertices for a smooth curve?

Comment: Hello :). To lower the polycount, try to use max 2 levels of *Subdivision* on your model. You'll need to think better about your topology, add more loopcuts and perhaps a *Bevel modifier*. But there's absolutely no need to use 5 levels for a smooth surface. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks, I lowered the levels of subdivision to 2 and added a few loops cuts to the front and back side of the wing and the wing looks almost as good as a high poly version. However, I'm having shading issues along the edges. Any way I should fix that?

Comment: Hi :). Shading issues can have many reasons. Please edit your question to point out this problem, and add an image of the problem (and possibly [upload your .blend file](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/)) :).